# Arabic with diacritics renders weird - html iOS with webfonts

Tags: html, ios, css, arabic, diacritics

I have been debugging this for days, and no luck. The html page I am developing, has Arabic text. When using a webfont, Arabic text with diacritics does not render well. Words are too close to one another, often overlapping, and paragraphs have leading space, and text is clipped at the end. Things render well when diacritics are not present. Things render well without webfonts. The problem is just with iOS. I tried multiple webfonts. I tried many different things. Please help.

Comment: "Dear, Dr. Smith. My wife's unwell, and has various pains in her elbow and also abdomen. We're on a trip to India currently, so you can't examine her, but I've given her multiple medicines and none of them helped. Please help." :P Sorry for being a bit snarky there, but without some code, and knowing which fonts you tried, this is not really answerable...